# How can I use the Find method to perform a case insensitive search on the database field?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, heroku-postgres, sails-postgresql

I am unable to get the case insensitive search from the database using *Sails.js V1.0* + *Waterline ORM*. I am using *sails-postgresql* adapter. The running environment is *Heroku* + *Heroku PostgreSQL*.

Is there any way to turn off the following setting in database adapter - *For performance reasons, case-sensitivity of contains depends on the database adapter.*

**Tried the method:**

Datastore configuration is:

```
default: {
  adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
  url: 'postgres://....',
  ssl: true,
  wlNext: {
    caseSensitive: true
  }
}
```

The code block is:

```
var meetings = await Meeting.find({
  select: ['id', 'uid', 'name', 'deleted', 'complete'],
  where: {
    owner: user.id,
    name: { contains: searchJson.name } : ""
  },
  skip: (inputs.page > 0) ? (inputs.page) : 0,
  limit: (inputs.limit > 0) ? (inputs.limit) : 10,
  sort: 'date DESC'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to handle this and case-insensitive unique indexes with PG/Sails is to use the [citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/citext.html) column type instead of `text`/`character varying` types (compared to forcing everything to lowercase which stinks).

`citext` is a case insensitive text datatype. "Essentially, it internally calls lower when comparing values. Otherwise, it behaves almost exactly like text."

An example model attribute pulled from a working app:

```js
username: {
  type: 'string',
  columnType: 'citext',
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  description: 'A users.. Username',
  // ...
},
```

According to [this (somewhat irellevant) Heroku docs page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search#data-types) this looks like it should work, but you may need to run `create extension citext;` on your database first.

Comment: What option do we have with Sails v1.2.4 and mongodb?

Comment: Faced a similar issue, but also materialized views had dependencies on a table I wanted to change column type. In this case, you'll need to drop materialized views, then update the column of the table with the command below: "ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE citext;" and after that recreate materialized views that were dropped before.

Answer (score 1):

For MongoDB https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/7014.
From sails-mongo@1.2.0, you can chain on .meta({makeLikeModifierCaseInsensitive: true}) for a case-insensitive query.
Example

```
await User.find(criteria).meta({makeLikeModifierCaseInsensitive: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native queries, for example:

```
const eventTypesRows = await Meeting.getDatastore()
  .sendNativeQuery(\`SELECT "name" FROM meeting WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER($1)\`, [searchName]);
```